# How to format template with django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a django application. And I try to format some data.

So I have this method:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import locale
import re
from fileinput import filename
from itertools import zip_longest
from locale import LC_NUMERIC, atof

import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

class FilterText:

def show_extracted_data_from_file(self):
       

        verdi_total_fruit = [12, 13, 14]
        verdi_fruit_name = ["watermeloenen", "appels", "winterpeen"]
        verdi_cost = [123, 55, 124, 88, 123, 123]

        regexes = [verdi_total_fruit, verdi_fruit_name, verdi_cost]
        matches = [(regex) for regex in regexes]       
       
        return tabulate(
            zip_longest(*matches),  # type: ignore
            headers=[
                "aantal fruit",
                "naam fruit",
                "kosten fruit",
            ],
        )
```

views:

```
def test(request):
    filter_text = FilterText()
    content = ""
    content = filter_text.show_extracted_data_from_file()
    context = {"content": content}
    return render(request, "main/test.html", context)
```

template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Create a Profile</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/custom-style.css' %}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/bootstrap.css' %}" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container center">
            <span class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="inline-div">
                    <form class="form-inline" action="/controlepunt140" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <div class="d-grid gap-3">
                            <div class="form-group">                                

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-outline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="wishlist">
                                        {{content}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </span>
            <span class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="inline-div">
                    <div class="d-grid gap-3">
                        <div class="form-group">

                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </span>

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

that produces this result:

```
 aantal fruit naam fruit kosten fruit -------------- ------------- -------------- 12 watermeloenen 123 13 appels 55 14 winterpeen 124 88 123 123
```

but as you can see it is one horizontal output.

But I want every item under each other. that it will looks like:

```
6  Watermeloenen 577,50
75 Watermeloenen  69,30
9  watermeloenen  46,20
```

a
Question: how to format the template?

if I do this:

```
 print(tabulate(
            zip_longest(*matches),  # type: ignore
            headers=[
                "aantal fruit",
                "naam fruit",
                "kosten fruit",
            ],
        ))
```

it looks correct:

```
 aantal fruit  naam fruit     kosten fruit
--------------  -------------  --------------
            16  Watermeloenen  123,20
           360  Watermeloenen  2.772,00
             6  Watermeloenen  46,20
            75  Watermeloenen  577,50
             9  Watermeloenen  69,30
           688  Appels         3.488,16
            22  Sinaasappels   137,50
            80  Sinaasappels   500,00
           160  Sinaasappels   1.000,00
           320  Sinaasappels   2.000,00
           160  Sinaasappels   1.000,00
            61  Sinaasappels   381,25
```

But not in the template

so this:

```
  return tabulate(
            zip_longest(*matches),  # type: ignore
            headers=[
                "aantal fruit",
                "naam fruit",
                "kosten fruit",
            ],tablefmt="html"
        )
```

then the output is this:

```
<table> <thead> <tr><th style="text-align: right;"> aantal fruit</th><th>naam fruit </th><th style="text-align: right;"> kosten fruit</th></tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr><td style="text-align: right;"> 12</td><td>watermeloenen</td><td style="text-align: right;"> 123</td></tr> <tr><td style="text-align: right;"> 13</td><td>appels </td><td style="text-align: right;"> 55</td></tr> <tr><td style="text-align: right;"> 14</td><td>winterpeen </td><td style="text-align: right;"> 124</td></tr> <tr><td style="text-align: right;"> </td><td> </td><td style="text-align: right;"> 88</td></tr> <tr><td style="text-align: right;"> </td><td> </td><td style="text-align: right;"> 123</td></tr> <tr><td style="text-align: right;"> </td><td> </td><td style="text-align: right;"> 123</td></tr> </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Your output of `content` is all in a single table row (`<tr>`).

Comment: @dgw. Yes, but how to improve this?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton It depends on what package you are using that provides the `tabulate` function, but the first thing I would try is to move the `for` and `endfor` pieces outside the `<tr>` tags.

Comment: @voodoo-burger. I am using the tabulate package.

Comment: @voodoo-burger. I have done that. But then it will display as one long vertical string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tabulate` package requires a third parameter `tablefmt` in order to output HTML, so you need to pass `tablefmt="html"` to the `tabulate()` function after `headers`.

```
    return tabulate(
        zip_longest(*matches),  # type: ignore
        headers=[
            "aantal fruit",
            "naam fruit",
            "kosten fruit",
        ],
        tablefmt="html",
    )
```

You will need to wrap this output with `mark_safe()` from `django.utils.safestring`.

Note that this produces an entire HTML table with all tags, so instead of looping over the table rows you can simply output `content` by itself:

```
<div class="wishlist">
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

At this point it's worth renaming `content` to something more appropriate like `table`.

Comment: @voodoo-burger.I made a reproducible example. But this doesn;t work.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton You will need to be a little more specific than "it doesn't work". What output are you seeing now?

Comment: @voodoo-burger.But you can test it. I made an example code fragment.

Comment: @voodoo-burger.I did that. But then you  will see literallythe html code

Comment: @mightycodeNewton I updated the answer, you need to apply `mark_safe()` to the output of the `tabulate()` function.

Comment: @voodoo-burger.Ah, oke. But where I have to add: mark_save?  I don't see that in your answare.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton `return mark_safe(tabulate(...))`